# How to optimize multiple numbers into a single short string and then reconvert back?

Tags: c++, string, optimization, numbers, libraries

I forgot the name, but sometime back I had come across a Javascript library which would take multiple integers as input and then return a very optimized string. This string can be reconverted back to those multiple integers when needed.

Is there any such library in C++ which does that?

Answer (score 2):

After browsing the old code in Javascript, I found our that the library which I came across was [**Hashids**](https://hashids.org/cpp/) and it has C++ support as well.